# Pymssql Error when trying to connect to SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, pymssql

I need help....

So I am trying to connect to db that is connected to a program in our business Desktop. The program is owned by a company but I got a permission to access the app db since it only has our company informations. Using Sql server management studio I can clearly see and connect to the db. However when I try to connect using mssql it shows me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "harvester_of_tweets.py", line 11, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect(host='localhost',  user='username', password='password!', database='Database')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymssql.py", line 607, in connect
    raise OperationalError, e[0]
pymssql.OperationalError: DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
Net-Lib error during Connection refused Error 111 - Connection refused
```

I wrote this to connect to the db:

`conn = conn = pymssql.connect("DESKTOP-J8IS63J\SQLEXPRESS", "user", "pass", "DgtalLaundry")`

Please help me fix this.

Thanks

I tried using pyodbc but the same thing ended happening. I looked up and saw that the server might not be forwarded to a port. But we actually don't have sql server configurator so that I could check for it. And since the server is open in ssms I could clearly see that the server is there and I can connect to it

Comment: You can see which port it runs on if you run following: 

exec MASTER..xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'

Comment: Or select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null

Comment: Yeah, otherwise you wouldn't be able to run anything :)

Comment: @siggemannen So I tried it and it showed me no ports it was empty.  I also got failed to connect to server whenever I try to export Data tier db.

Comment: @siggemannen to be more specific this shows when I try to export data tier https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m2P4i7htLTdYAvUr6fQrwKsVeG2-xcI-/view

Comment: Both sql calls was empty?

Comment: @siggemannen Yes